# Where to store encryption key?

Tags: php, security, encryption, key

I'm currently finishing up a php program that backs up multiple Google Calendars which requires me to store email addresses and their passwords.  I'm using AES encryption (I'm not using a hash because I need two way encryption) and although all passwords are encrypted with the same key, each password has its own iv which is stored in the database with it.

I know there is no 100% guaranteed way to keep the data safe if someone can gain full access over my system but I was hoping for some suggestions of storage methods/storage places that makes life difficult for potential hackers.  Currently, I've considered putting the key in a file only the sole administrator has access to or setting an environmental variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232228/whats-the-best-method-to-use-store-encryption-keys-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've considered putting the key in a file only the sole administrator
>   has access to

if the system would be compromised (or having physical access to your hd), than an attacker can gain the access to your secret key.

I think the better solution is to hold somewhere in the fs an encrypted version of your key, protected with a passphrase to be entered manually everytime your secret keys are needed. Something like gpg key-ring.

Comment: If someone had access to the php files wouldn't they still have access to the key?

Comment: No..the key must be ALWAYS be stored in an encrypted form. The only way to have access to the unencrypted key is enter manually (need user interaction) the passphrase. Typically this mechanism is used by gpg. private key(asymmetric) is stored encrpypted (with a simmetric key derived from the passphrase) in the fs.

Comment: Entering a passphrase whenever a key is needed is not too practical because users can enter their information on a webpage whenever they want.  As such, I would not be able to enter the key to encrypt their information.  I was thinking that I store passwords in a semi encrypted state (pretty much encryption with a key that is accessible in the file system) and at a point that I can, enter a key myself that will be used to decrypt already stored passwords and re encrypt semi encrypted passwords

Comment: @RAD: ok..I didn't understand that point. In this key you can't store the key in an encrypted form, so all the security of the key depends on the security of your OS.

Comment: I just meant that I do not have control over when users enter their information  because it is entered into a webpage (when it would have to be encrypted) so I could not enter a key manually to encrypt.  I do however, how control over when the information is decrypted.

Comment: @Amir the php files are in the html directory and the key would not be

Comment: @0verbose: You're saying to use a public/private key pair so that I can encrypt with the public key but that doesn't really matter if others can get a hold of it and decrypt with my own private key when I need to

Comment: @RAD: no..i didn't say that. I said that gpg that use public/private key uses a symmetric key derived from a passphrase to store the private key as well.

Comment: @RAD: the point is simple. If you can't use human interaction to supply a passphrase everytime you need the secret key, then the secret key must be stored not encrypted.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Thanks