# Encrypting Emails, Hashing Passwords, and Storing them in DB?

Tags: php, mysql, security, web-applications

First off, my understanding of encrypting and hashing:

1. Encrypting - can be decrypted
2. Hashing - can NOT be unhashed

When building a web application, I should:

1. Encrypt the email address (will be used to login) with encryption key. It's nice to be able to decrypt email addresses for later use (e.g. emailing users)
2. Hash the password with a salt. No one should be able to see user's password, so hashing (since it is one-way) is good.

**If the above 2 points are right, where should I store the encryption key and salt?**

If I store it in the DB, the seems a bit pointless should the DB ever be compromised. The benefit, though, is that I can assign a unique encryption key and salt for each user.

Should I store the encryption key and salt in my application's configuration? If the DB is ever compromised, at least the encryption key and salt are not also compromised (hopefully). The problem with this is that it probably means that everyone shares the same encryption key and salt.

Suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Maybe you should try asking this over at http://security.stackexchange.com/ for some more paranoid opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encrypt the email at all, you need to do it with a common salt/key. Otherwise, how are you going to select a user by his email address from the db to check whether the hashed password is correct? You can't decrypt every email address every time.

Overall, I think there's very little to be gained from encrypting email addresses. Use MySQL database encryption if you want, but don't worry about this at the application level.

The salt for hashing the password should/needs to be unique and can be stored in the database, in fact it can be part of the hash itself. See http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ for a good implementation.

Comment: Email encryption doesn't have to be with a common salt/key. All that matters is that you know what that salt/key is when it comes to decryption time. Encrypting email addresses allow you to expose your DB without compromising people's email address, just like what SO did: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: OK, so you have a bunch of blobs of pseudo-random noise in your database. The user `foo@example.com` wants to log in. What do you do? Sure, there are ways to do it, like using the email address itself as the key to itself, but it's still more complexity for little gain. Exposing the database in the way SO does doesn't mean the email address is encrypted, it just means it's not exposed in the public interface.

Comment: Isn't there a gain in the event the DB is compromised? Wouldn't it be better if the email address itself was encrypted?

Comment: Since the email address needs to be decryptable, your server is able to decrypt it. If your database is compromised, most of the time your server is as well. It would only add a benefit in case the database is compromised but the attacker cannot look at your application files, which IMO is rather rare (but again, you may want to ask more paranoid security experts about this).

Comment: @deceze - You asked for more paranoid opinions, maybe i can help out here :-) There are many attacks, which allow to execute queries on a db, without having admin rights on the server. Unencrypted email addresses will be an interesting target then. In addition, db-server and web-server are often located on different computers, having control over the db-server would be enought to get unencrypted email addresses.

Comment: @martin Of course, I fully realize that there are attacks against databases only (SQL injection and so forth). But in this case encrypting email addresses is probably not your biggest concern. I'd propose to invest the time into securing the database properly instead of introducing extra complexity into the app by encrypting emails. Since emails are often a primary key or at least a primary piece of information, you're precluding proper indexing and searching by encrypting them. It's a tradeoff that's not worth it, IMO. I'd like to see real-world examples of this though.

Comment: @deceze - In the end it's the same question as with an operating system, shall we make it bulletproof (fix every possible security hole), or shall we prevent the worst damage on the system (no admin rights). Probably both, most would answer. Of course it adds complexity (adding an additional hash field for searching). So i would ask myself the question: do people mind if it's known that their email is connected to this site?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding seems correct to me.

**Password**: Only the hash of a password should be stored, together with a user specific salt. The salt can be stored plaintext, the reason for the salt is, that an attacker cannot use one single rainbowtable for all users (building a rainbowtable is expensive). It's recommended to use the `hash_hmac()` function.

**EMail**: I think it's a good idea to encrypt these adresses, but however you do it, if the attacker has control over the server, he will be able to recover these addresses. I would put a secret key in a separate directory, which is outside the web root (cannot be accessed directly from the web). Don't write it in a file that can be delivered without interpreting, the extension *.php is better than *.inc . If you have no access to such a directory, at least make one and protect it with .htaccess `Deny from all`.

If you need to find an email address in the DB you can additionally store a hash, this allows to search case insensitive (first turn to lowercase, then generate the hash).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "If you need to find an email address in the DB you can additionally store a hash"?

Comment: Maybe the user has to enter email and password to login, then your application has to find the user. To find the user you need to search the database for this specific email address. You could encrypt the email before searching, but it would be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The salt should be per-user, and can be indeed in the database; thus the point of a salt is  that someone with a copy of your db can't work on cracking all the passwords at once, but each separately.

As for the encryption key, that's a much harder issue - definitely don't store it in the database; if your platform offers any kind of protected storage, you may want to use that. See e.g. this for useful answers: [What's the best method to use / store encryption keys in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232228/whats-the-best-method-to-use-store-encryption-keys-in-mysql)